# Join one column to two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that holds info for accounts, posts, and which posts a user likes.

```
AccountData
id || username

PostData
id || text || accountid

LikesDislikesData
liked(bool) || accountid || postid
```

I have a view set up because I need specific data from the DB to bind inside of my app. Here is the code I am using:

```
  SELECT trippin.PostData.id, trippin.AccountData.username, trippin.PostData.posttext,     
    trippin.CategoryData.categoryname, trippin.PostData.__createdat as CreatedAt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN likes.liked = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Likes, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN likes.liked = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DisLikes
FROM trippin.PostData    
INNER JOIN trippin.AccountData ON trippin.PostData.accountid = trippin.AccountData.id
INNER JOIN trippin.CategoryData ON trippin.CategoryData.id = trippin.PostData.categoryid
LEFT OUTER JOIN trippin.LikesDislikesData likes ON likes.postid = trippin.PostData.id
GROUP BY (trippin.AccountData.username), (trippin.PostData.posttext), (trippin.PostData.id), (trippin.categorydata.categoryname), (trippin.PostData.__createdat)
```

The problem is that, any time I add a join to (likes.accountid = trippin.AccountData.id), rows are either duplicated or the output is just incorrect.

I think it might be a design issue, but I am not sure and cannot find anything that helps my exact problem.

So basically, each post is made by a user. Then, each post is liked or disliked (or nothing) by other users. I need all of this data inside of a view so I can pass it to my app.

Comment: I'm assuming one row in LikesDislikesData = one like or dislike...so you'll have many rows in this table for any given postID?  If that's a correct assumption and you are just looking to get totals of likes, join to a subselect on LikesDislikesData that does a count and groups by accountID (Thus giving you one row per accountID to join to)

Comment: what data do you want to select? should one row be one like/dislike in your result? or do you want to select all posts even those without any likes?

Comment: I want every post. I also want a column that has a count of how many likes (liked = true) and dislikes (liked = false) each post has.

Perhaps I am going about this wrong. So yes I would have the same post more than once I guess. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @Twelfth -- I will try to do what you're saying, though last time I did any SQL (besides now) was 1.5 years ago and I took one class on it. Will get back to you on the success/lack of.

Comment: if you inner join the account there will be duplicate rows, if in the table account are multiple rows with the same id. and a row will disappear if the post.accountid is not found in account.id (so post from deleted accounts wont be in your result).

Comment: Actually, I don't think this will work for what I need. I need to change my design. I can't have duplicate posts. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
select postID
  , sum(case when liked = true then 1 else 0 end) as liked
  , sum(case when liked = true then 1 else 0 end) as disliked
from trippin.LikesDislikesData
group by postID
```

The above statement should give you liked and disliked by post ID.   Call it a subquery and join to your main:

```
SELECT trippin.PostData.id, trippin.AccountData.username, trippin.PostData.posttext,     
trippin.CategoryData.categoryname, trippin.PostData.__createdat as CreatedAt,
Likes, 
DisLikes
FROM trippin.PostData    
INNER JOIN trippin.AccountData ON trippin.PostData.accountid = trippin.AccountData.id
INNER JOIN trippin.CategoryData ON trippin.CategoryData.id = trippin.PostData.categoryid
LEFT OUTER JOIN   (
  select postID
  , sum(case when liked = true then 1 else 0 end) as liked
  , sum(case when liked = true then 1 else 0 end) as disliked
from trippin.LikesDislikesData
group by postID)
likes ON likes.postid = trippin.PostData.id
```

Should work for what you are after.  I removed your group by clause as you'll no longer need the sums syntax.  Quite often you'll find creating a subquery to do counts and sums by ID and joining that to the main query by that ID will be the easiest solution to obtain counts...atleast without having to group by the entire select statement

Comment: Thank you. But I think I have a deeper problem. I'll explain:

I can't have duplicate post data. I am passing this information to an object in c#. Having duplicate posts will not work, so I think I need to check my design or check my implementation in C#. Thank you for the help, though.